# Application memory usage decrese

Tags: c++, memory, ffmpeg

I have an application which actively uses ffmpeg for video decoding. The interesting thing which I discovered, is that after some time(hour or two) the memory usage is decreasing for about 20-25%. (e.g. from 260Mb to 200 Mb). I am wondering if this due to some specifics of the ffmpeg implementation? Or maybe this kind of memory fluctuations can happen if the memory is used actively.

I am running on x86_64 Ubuntu. The compiler is clang with libc++.

Answer (score 0):

you could trace the memory usage by strace.

```
strace -e trace=memory -o out.log <your app>
```